# DataTemplate for ItemTemplate of a Grid displaying its content in columns

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I have `HeaderedItemsControl` which ItemsSource is bound to a `ObservableCollection<Person>`. I would like to display it's content like:

```
*Name*       Müller      Schmid    Weber
*FirstName*  Peter       Hans      Willhelm
*Age*        32          56        78
*Country*    Switzerland Austria   Liechtenstein
```

My xaml-Code so far:

```
<HeaderedItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PersonCollection}">
        <HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Name"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="FirstName"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Age"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="Country"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
        <HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding Path=Age}" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="{Binding Path=Country}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </HeaderedItemsControl>
```

This gives me something like:

```
*Name*       Müller
             Schmid
             Weber
*FirstName*  Peter
             Hans
             Willhelm
*Age*        32
             56 
             78
*Country*    Switzerland
             Austria
             Liechtenstein
```

Is there a way to let the items be presented in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ControlTemplate you've wrapped your ItemsPresenter in a StackPanel, which in this case is doing nothing because it has a single child: the ItemsPresenter. What you actually want is for the ItemsPresenter to use that StackPanel to do its internal layout which you achieve using the ItemsControl.ItemsPanel to define template for a panel that will host the items generated by the control:

```
<HeaderedItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</HeaderedItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

You also need to change the StackPanel declaration in your ItemTemplate to Grid so that it will lay out each item into Rows.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now my table looks like what I want it to.  
I removed the StackPanel that wrapped the ItemsPresenter, set the ItemsPresenter Grid.Row and Grid.Column.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like within your `ItemTemplate` you are setting the row of your Labels instead of the columns, so your content would stack vertically. Also, you have the Labels sitting in a `StackPanel` with vertical orientation, which will make them display in a single column. I'm guessing you are looking for a layout like this for your `ItemTemplate`.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
  <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
  <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Path=Age}" />
  <Label Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding Path=Country}"/>
</Grid>
```